# bootstrap text size very small on desktop and good at smaller screen size and mobile device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for my web site. I don't know why my page's text sizes are very small on any browser on my desktop device. But the text sizes were fine on smaller screen and mobile device. Here is my page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>My Home Page</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<!--<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"> -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>

</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="abc.html">abc</a></li>
    <li><a href="cde.html">cde</a></li>
    <li><a href="123.html">123</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container text-center">   
 <!-- <h3>ABC </h3><br> -->
 <br/>

 <p>this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this   is   a test. this is a test.this is a test. this is a test.this is a test. this    is a test.this is a test. this is a test.this is a test. this is a    test.this is a test. this is a test.this is a test. this is a test.this is atn test. this is a test.this is a test. this is a test.this is a test. this is a test.this is a test. this is a test.
</p>


 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I checked your code. Text size fine. Once you check your browser ZOOM level.

Comment: Try to use bootstrap media query breakpoints https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put this in my css to make the text size normal on my desktop device.

```
 body {
     font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
     line-height: 1.8;
  ?* color: #f5f6f7; */
 }
 p {font-size: 19px;}
```